# AsyncStorage : React Native

Tags: session, react-native, asyncstorage

Save 'unique Id' as session variable in react native

Comment: Please precise your question with some codes or print screen because your   question seem not clear.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please add some code samples so we can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the unique id using `AsyncStorage` like this :

```
import { AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

AsyncStorage.setItem('Key Name', uniqueId)
```

And after that you can get from other component like this :

```
import { AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

AsyncStorage.getItem('Key Name').then((value) => console.log(value))
```

For details you can read from the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html). I hope this answer can help you.

Comment: Once it is saved using `AsynStorage.setItem` then can i use it in other pages by using `AsyncStorage.getItem` ?

Comment: Cool @anu, i am very pleased to help you

Answer (score 3):

```
import { AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
AsyncStorage.getItem('Key Name').then((value) => console.log(value))
```

we can get value from asyncstorage in any component of app.

number of another function are used like merge,remove etc.please see [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)